# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `byte[]` from String

Tags: java, android, json, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am developing an Android App with a Java Backend using Spring Data JPA. One of my classes represents a profile image and contains the following field:

```
 @Lob
    @Column(name = "image")
    private byte[] image;
```

When i invoke the Rest API that saves the above class the JSON request looks like this:

```
{"image":"[B@23bafb3"}
```

Then the described error occurs. I have seen suggestions of declaring the image as string and then get the bytes but this does not seem a good practice to me.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is with the serialization of the `byte[]` to JSON. The default serialization of a `byte[]` in Java will result in the string representation you have shown which is not a valid format for a binary image.

To correctly serialize the `byte[]` as a base64 encoded string, you can use a custom serializer/deserializer in your API. One option is to use the `Base64` class in Java to encode the `byte[]` as a string and then decode the string back to a `byte[]` during deserialization.

Comment: As per @Yacine, you can't put a byte[] in JSON because to contains non-readable characters. it is standard practice to Base64 encode (to a readable character only) String so that it can be serialised to JSON.